# swfupload + jQuery: upload_complete_handler not firing

Tags: jquery, swfupload

I'm trying to assign a done-event to the upload_complete_handler for swfupload, unfortunately nothing happens.

In my settings I have:

```
upload_complete_handler : function(){ 
    alert("finished");
}
```

All parameters seem correct, I've already tried deactivating my upload script. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had been looking for something to redirect after all upload complete. And based on your question this works fine immediatelly. So this code is OK except handler type -

- upload_complete_handler is for every file (after upload),
- queue_complete_handler is after all files complete.

  ...
  upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
  upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
  queue_complete_handler : function(){window.location.href="/your address";}

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to render something (output some text/HTML or even nothing with at least a 200 Success response) for the `upload_complete_handler` to fire. Are you outputting anything or are you just doing something with the file?